# Qt OpenGL with Widgets : what's wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

So, I've been paying around with OpenGL for a while, and now I'd like to migrate to Qt so I can embed widgets on my window.
Since I need Qt Widgets, I do not want to use `QWindow`; thus I use `QGLWidget` that I put in a container window.
I did manage to create a correct context and set a clear color, but I don't manage to draw anything.

Could you help me to understand why?
(BTW, I feel like I'm doing dirty things. If you have something cleaner to tell me that allows me to embed a GL surface as a widget, tell me!)

**My main:**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QGLFormat glFormat;
  glFormat.setVersion(3, 3);
  glFormat.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile); // Requires >=Qt-4.8.0
  glFormat.setSampleBuffers(true);

  QWidget window;
  window.resize(1000, 800);
  WidgetOpenGL* GL = new WidgetOpenGL(glFormat, &window);
  GL->resize(500, 500);
  window.show();

  //GL->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

**WidgetOpenGL.h:**

```
class WidgetOpenGL : public QGLWidget, protected QGLFunctions
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  WidgetOpenGL(const QGLFormat& format, QWidget* parent = nullptr);

protected:
  void initializeGL();
  void paintGL();
  void resizeGL(int width, int height);

signals:

public slots :
};
```

**Implementation:**

```
#include "widgetopengl.h"

WidgetOpenGL::WidgetOpenGL(const QGLFormat& format, QWidget* parent) : QGLWidget(format, parent), QGLFunctions()
{
    makeCurrent();
    initializeGLFunctions(context());    
}

void WidgetOpenGL::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    
}

void WidgetOpenGL::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float vertices[] = {-0.5, -0.5,   0.0, 0.5,   0.5, -0.5};    

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);   

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);        
}

void WidgetOpenGL::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    int side = qMin(width, height);
    glViewport((width - side) / 2, (height - side) / 2, side, side);    
}
```

Comment: I'm far from an expert on this, but:  Does the widget need to be explicitly added to a layout belonging to the window?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean, but I do want the widget to have a parent window

Comment: I meant something like this (maybe with a layout type other than QBoxLayout, if you preferred):  auto layout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom); window.setLayout(layout); layout->addWidget(GL);

Comment: @mjwach : Nice trick (I didn't know about this) for smart resizing. Thanks for it. But I think my problems lies in either OpenGL or Qt's OpenGL module

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out the problem(S).

Well, at least I've found out a better way to achieve what I want.

I was using QGLWidget and QGLFunctions, which are deprecated.
By using QOpenGLWidget and QOpenGLFunctions instead, I got what I wanted to get. It's really simple, just had to look at the doc